# How to pass two columns of a dataframe to a function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying out this below code. But I am returned with the error

> **("Newmethod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'B'", 'occurred at index 0')**

```
def Newmethod(A,B):
  Add=A+B
  return Add

Df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=["A","B","C"])
Df['D']=Df[['A','B']].apply(Newmethod, axis=1)
```

What do I miss here? Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it

```
Df['D']=Df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x:Newmethod(x.A,x.B), axis=1)

   A  B  C   D
0  1  2  3   3
1  4  5  6   9
2  7  8  9  15
```

**Explain**

You can use `np.sum` or change your `Newmethod()`. Otherwise, you can only do this in your form.

```
import numpy as np
Df['D']=Df[['A','B']].apply(np.sum, axis=1)
# or
def Newmethod(x):
    Add= x.A + x.B
    return Add
Df['D']=Df[['A','B']].apply(Newmethod, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes got it thanks. Can you please tell me without using lambda also.

Comment: What does it mean not to use lambda? `df['D']=df['A']+df['B']` also can do it.

Comment: Does this code Df['D']=Df[['A','B']].apply(Newmethod, axis=1) must use lambda to pass two columns to a function as like the solution provided above ?

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me alot.

Comment: @RajaSaheS You're welcome. Please accpet answer if it's helpful and no problem.